# can anyone tell me the equivalent class of j2se for blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I want to know which types in blackberry that i can use instead of these j2se types:

```
Iterator
Collections
StringTokenizer
HashMap
ArrayList
Map
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Vector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Vector.html) class for lists and the [Hashtable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html) class for maps.  As for StringTokenizer, depending on what type of delimiters you're splitting on you may find something useful in the [StringUtilities](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/StringUtilities.html) class.

Comment: and what about Softreference class and Rectangle2D

Comment: Well there is the similar "WeakReference" class, but nothing close to Rectangle2D